# Solving unknown complex number w

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a complex number $w$= a + bi such that $w$$\bar{w}$ = 25  and $w$ + $\bar{w}$ = 8. I assume from this that the complex number in question hast two values. I've already solved the $w$ + $\bar{w}$ = 8 equation, but I'm having problems with $w$$\bar{w}$ = 25.

I've narrowed the equation down to $a^2$+$b^2$=25 but I don't know how to solve the rest. Or if I'm at least on right tracks.

I  suck at this stuff and I've tried over and over again but just can't make it.

Answer (score 2):

$w+\bar w=8$ means $a=4$. Then we can find $b$ using $a^2+b^2=25$.